# How to increase the efficiency of building android project of multiple channels by gradle

Tags: java, android, ant, gradle

I am working on an android project.I want to build this project by gradle. And I need to generate 20 apk files according to the different market channels.The difference of the files is that in the manifest file ,I need to replace the string"UMENG_VALUE"with each channel name.
My current way is to use product flavor like this:

```
productFlavors {
  develop{}
  official{}
  ika{}

}


 android.applicationVariants.all{variant ->
            def manifestFile="${buildDir}/intermediates/manifests/${variant.dirName}/AndroidManifest.xml"


    new File(manifestFile).write(new File(manifestFile).getText('UTF-8').replaceAll("@string/channel_id", "${variant.productFlavors[0].name}"), 'UTF-8')


    variant.processResources.manifestFile = file("${buildDir}/intermediates/manifests/${variant.dirName}/AndroidManifest.xml")



  }
```

But the problem of this method is that gradle will execute every task according to each flavor right? But in my opinion , most of the steps are exactly the same. So is there a better way for gradle to just compile and dex for only one time and just change the String in manifest file?